# MySQL Partitioning: SELECT by ID, but DELETE by date

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-partitioning

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `uid` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `time` bigint(14) NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `time_type_uid` (`time`,`type`,`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I basically do:

- `INSERT` ~1 million rows per day, current size is about 100 million entries
- `DELETE` all rows older than 100 days:

  - Statement #1: `DELETE FROM event WHERE time < unix_timestamp()-100*86400;`
  - Statement #2: `DELETE FROM event WHERE time < unix_timestamp()-100*86400 LIMIT 1000;`
- Users will `SELECT` all events by UID, about 500 queries a day in sum, so not that quite much:

  - Statement #1: `SELECT * FROM event WHERE uid=4711 AND type IN (23,1002,12,1);`
  - Statement #2: `SELECT * FROM event WHERE uid=4711 AND type IN (23,1002,12,1) AND time BETWEEN 1381051061 AND 1381051861;`

Handling this table became quite slow, especially since the `DELETE` job blocks `INSERT`s/`SELECT`s on the table. We tried a daily bulk `DELETE` as explained above (Statement #1), which doesn't work any more without blocking the table. Currently we're deleting every 30 seconds (Statement #2), but this will block for 10 seconds.

We're planning to increase the `INSERT` load, but first tests lead to threads hanging in "System block" state, I guess this is due to I/O. Server settings are optimized as suggested by mysqltuner.pl. Hardware system has definitely I/O issues and is "as is", unfortunately it cannot be changed for several reasons. We don't even have root access.

Is partitioning even a solution and is MyISAM the best engine to use? We are in the need of optimizing anything we can before improving the hardware.

Comment: Voting to close:  too broad.  Fascinating problem, but too broad to definitively answer here, and arguably not strictly a programming problem.  We can tell you how to partition, but we can't optimize in the abstract.  Why not InnoDB?  What are the server settings?  What are system specs and load?  What other queries are running?  How often do you DELETE, and could it be more frequent?  Do you have the right indices for your pattern of query?  (My guess is, not quite.)  Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know it's kind of difficult to give optimization tips for a broad problem. I figured that handling data like this might be a generic problem. I added some more details, hope it helps.

Comment: dba.stackexchange might be a better place to ask what kinds of optimization are appropriate and how you'd measure their effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [InnoDB with snapshot isolation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) to obtain a readable snapshot. That way readers are not blocked by your big delete jobs. I don't think you should go to partitioning for this fairly standard situation. Partitioning is a big hammer and invasive. Maybe some simple measures are enough.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go to the trouble of partitioning (which performs nicely but can be a sysadmin hairball) try a couple of things.

Run your DELETE cleanout operation multiple times a day (even multiple times an hour), so it doesn't have to whack a million rows every time it runs.

Try running

```
    DELETE FROM event
          WHERE TIME < < unix_timestamp()-100*86400
         LIMIT 10000
```

over and over again.  This will reduce the amount of time each DELETE operation locks up your table, and free it up for other operations.

Figure out whether you have the right composite index (time, type, uid).  The queries you've shown us don't exploit that index, and indexes take up time when you're inserting.  It looks like you might try simply deleting that index.  You might want an index on (uid,type) for the query you mention.

Get rid of the use of `SELECT *`.  Instead, retrieve only the columns your application needs. MySQL can do surprising optimizations when it knows exactly what data items you need.

Can you afford any daily or weekly downtime?  If so, use

```
 OPTIMIZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE  event
```

once in a while to tidy up your table and index structures.

Comment: Thanks, we already tried deleting with limit. It works, but blocks for about 10 seconds. Will definitely not work with more INSERTs at the same time.